# Javascript Lookup table vs else if and multiple matching results

Tags: javascript, object, literals, lookup-tables

I'm creating a canvas game for fun, and I'm trying to re-factor some of my multiple else if statements to use object lookup tables instead.

This is my current code for assigning variable values on keydown:

```
function keyDown(e) {
  keypressed = true;

  if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 68) {rightKey = true; }
  else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 65) {leftKey = true;}
  else if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 87) {upKey = true; }
  else if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 83) {downKey = true; }
  else if (e.keyCode == 80) { isPaused = !isPaused; document.body.classList.toggle('pause'); }

  if (e.keyCode === 69) { startHit(); }
}
```

I want to assign both wsad keys and the arrow keys to do the same thing, thus the use of || in the if conditions.

I read that using an object literal lookup table is a faster way to achieve this and this is my attempt:

```
var codes = {
    39 : function() {
      return rightKey = true;
    },
    37 : function() {
      return leftKey = true;
    },
    38 : function() {
      return upKey = true;
    },
    40 : function() {
      return downKey = true;
    },
    80 : function() {
      isPaued = !isPaused;
      document.body.classList.toggle('pause');
    },
    69 : startHit
}

codes[68] = codes[39];
codes[65] = codes[37];
codes[87] = codes[38];
codes[83] = codes[40];

function keyDown(e) {
    keypressed = true;
    codes[e.keyCode]();
}
```

This works just fine, but I'm not sure the assignment of the bottom keys is the best way to do this? I can't obviously use the || operator in the left hand assignment, so would there be a cleaner way to do this or should I just stick with the else ifs?

Also, I know I could use a switch statement, but I feel like it would look similar to the way I've done above.

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement?

```
function keyDown(e) {
    keypressed = true;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 39:
        case 68:
            rightKey = true;
            break;
        case 37:
        case 65: 
            leftKey = true;
            break;
        case 38:
        case 87: 
            upKey = true; 
            break;
        case 40:
        case 83: 
            downKey = true;
            break;
        case 80:
            isPaused = !isPaused; 
            document.body.classList.toggle('pause');
            break;
        case 69:
            startHit(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution. I wasn't aware I could have both cases together for each condition! (although switch statement syntax looks kinda strange :D)

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
var codes = function (){
  function rightKey(){
    rightKey = true;
  }

  function leftKey() {
    leftKey = true;
  }

  return {
    39 : rightKey,
    37 : leftKey,
    '...': '...',
    68 : rightKey,
    65 : leftKey

}}()
```

Comment: Yea, I thought this sort of thing would be the way to do it. My only concern is the repeating part for the duplicate values - 39 : rightKey, 68 : rightKey. Does this not now make the code more verbose than the if statements or would it still be more efficient this way? While we're on efficiency, we're calling functions here to return the keyValue; which has the most overhead out of calling the functions or evaluating the if statements?

Comment: IF statement should be faster.  But, at first I think modern js engines can optimize such function calls and it will almost the same efficiency, at second are you sure you need such low level of optimization?

Comment: What about <duplicate values - 39 : rightKey, 68 : rightKey> it efficiency is exactly same as your proposed variant